# Join two excel tables

Tags: excel, join

I need a little help. I would like to join 2 excel tables.

First table is enormous (200.000 rows). Here I have serial numbers, mac address and group numbers. Each serial number have unique mac address (obviously). Serials and macs are grouped with group number.

Second table is smaller (5000 rows). Here I have serial numbers in mac address.

I would like to to insert group numbers from first table to second table.

Is there any easy way to solve my problem?

Table1
[image]

Table2
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is a Lookup too slow to solve your issue?

Enter this into C2:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Table1!$B$2:$C$200001,2,FALSE)
```

Then copy C2 to C3:C5001